# Return No Record Found Value in PDO::FETCH_OBJ Loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to add an if/then into my PDO::FETCH_OBJ result statement to display a "No Records Found" message if the query is blank.

My working query:

```
          <?php
          $command  = "SELECT ";
          $command .= "id, ";
          $command .= "firstName, ";
          $command .= "FROM mytable ";
          $command .= "ORDER BY sortOrder";

          $STH = $DBH->query($command);  

          $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);  

          while($row = $STH->fetch()) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="view/?b=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->firstName; ?></a></td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

I was able to find similar code that would work for an array, but I can't get it to work with the FETCH_OBJ code above.

This is similar code that illustrates the if/then I would like to implement:

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
  $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

  if ( count($result) ) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
      print_r($row);
    }  
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
```

I'm brand new to PDO so I'm sure it's a context issue, I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable to determine if you found any rows during the loop.

```
$no_rows_found = true;
while ($row = $STH->fetch() {
    $no_rows_found = false;
    ...
}

if ($no_rows_found) {
    echo "No rows found";
}
```